# How Check combobox c# not select same index

Tags: c#, combobox

[1 Choose  Normal Or special](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8LAv.png)

[2 Choose special Price+5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxRRs.png)

3 Choose Normal  Price-5

4 But Choose same is Price double

```
private void comboType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblProID.Text == "")
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Please Find Food");
            txtAmount.Text = "";
            buttonFind.Focus();
        }
        else if (comboType.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            lblProCost.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(lblProCost.Text) + (5)).ToString("#,##0.00");
        }
        else 
        {
            lblProCost.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(lblProCost.Text) - (5)).ToString("#,##0.00");
        }
    }
```

Logic  IF Select Normal (Price -5)
       else Select special (Price +5)
I want to check If Select same index not Sum price
Or You have idea New For Help Me ! Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a variable / property on the form level that stores the previous combobox selected index value and you could compare comboType.selectedIndex with that variable - if the same do nothing, else do something and overwrite this variable. 
The other way is to derive your own class from the combobox and implement the variable on the combobox devided class level + add a method that checks if selected index is the same - return true if not return false but also overwrite the old selected index value.